# I have what I believe are my address and password - don't know what wallet from 2017

Tags: lost-wallet

I have what appears to be a GUID and a password.  But no recollection what service I used of if I even purchased / transferred or made a transaction with them back in 2017.  Any way to check to see if I have anything in here and retrieve it?  My current BTC is on a platform I use regularly, this was prior to me setting up my current process last year...  Any advice?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to help you with so little information. If I were you I'd search my emails for a service I could have used at the time, then try their restoration process if any, and contact their customer service (if any). Can't help more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a very old Blockchain.info wallet, they're the only ones using a GUID for the identifier.

Comment: Thanks - it worked.  Balance was ZERO.  Much appreciated your help with this found losing lottery ticket however!!!  Dreams live on.